# Origin of consciousness

Tags: consciousness, emotions

Is it possible that consciousness arose because of the conflict between  'self interest' and 'pack interest'? Does the 'level of consciousness' depend on the 'size of the pack'?

Humans are social creatures. That's just a nice way of saying that we're pack animals. But packs don't work if each individual only looks after his own best interest. This is why we evolved emotions such as guilt and pride.

Comment: Any interest to survive would be superfluous when every aspect of a creature's theoretical constitution has evolved for that purpose and that purpose alone. Afterall, what use would a decision making process be if it opens up the possibility for a decision that wouldn't be conducive to survival? Therefore, consciousness, self interest and any other such ideas are inconsistent with the evolutionary paradigm. That also explains why inanimate objects such as rocks are much better "survivors" than people are: They don't choose to abide; they just do it.

Comment: Interesting writings on this general topic: Totem and Taboo; Civilization and its Discontents, Freud. And Eros and Civilization, Marcuse.

Comment: This could use a little more focus maybe? Possibly a good q to workshop in chat! Some editing tips: Focus on asking about the specific problem you’re running into. Do mention any research/reflection you’ve done. Try to indicate the “shape” of your problem: what does a great answer to this question look like in your mind?

Comment: Just a brain fart. But I'm thinking that reflex actions don't require consciousness or, let's say, minimal consciousness. Kinda like 'sense motion, respond' 'sense sound, respond'. No real 'thinking'. Comparing animals that hunt alone, to animals that hunt in packs, is there a difference in levels of consciousness?

Comment: Support from the opposite side: From a Nietsche/Darwin perspective, packs also do not work if individuals *don't* pursue variant interests -- they lose forward development of competitive advantages, and they are competed out.  It seems more likely that we were at some evolutionary stage more instinctively collective as a pack/herd animal (like school fish or herd gazelle).  Dennett considers something like this in his supposition that the genetic 'orienting signal' to which we would all respond identically evolves into an individual feedback loop that anchors conscious monitoring of time.

Comment: Collective behavior only requires that I inherit the impulse to do X when in a certain kind of trouble and the reflex to do Y to fix the problem whenever someone does X.  If X is a common enough problem (seeing a hyena), and Y is an effective enough solution (sounding alarm and 'counting' troupe members to see if anyone did not get away) it does not have to evolve on top of individualistic behavior.  This can happen the other way around.  If I make use of the alarm to do something else, more selfish, like find just my family members first, these can evolve the other way over.

Answer (score 1):

No, because this does not answer the hard problem of consciousness, how phenomenality can emerge from physical stuff.

Both "interests" would have to come from somewhere, at least from mental processes and presumably from processes with some degree of consciousness.

The idea also seems to have a skewed take on natural selection: living beings don't evolve for something or in order to do something. They mutate and whatever survives to reproduce passes on traits.  (Of course that's just one evolutionary mechanism.)

Emotions != consciousness.